# Regex - match http but not https with constraint

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, regex-lookarounds

PHP Regex

#### Source:

```
http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/image.jpg
https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/image2.jpg
http://example.com/wp-content/plugins/example-plugin/images/image.jpg
```

#### Objective

I want to match all strings that:

- Contains HTTP, but not HTTPS
- Contains `wp-content/uploads/`

.. and I do not want to capture the `wp-content/uploads/` part so that's a non-capturing group from what I can figure.

I have tried doing a positive-lookahead but I can't seem to get it right.
This is what I've come up with so far but I dont' know where to put the HTTP part. The regex tester at regex101 just doesnt match.

```
(?=(?:(wp-content\/uploads)+))
```

#### Update:

To clarify, I need simple regex, no PHP code. In other words, PCRE which PHP uses.

Comment: `if (parse_url($url, PHP_URL_SCHEME) == "https") { return false; }` not suitable for you?

Comment: Are your urls already isolated (each one is in a separated string) or are all of them inside a larger string?

Comment: These strings are present in post_content and other database columns on a WordPress installation. My objective is to replace http with https through search-and-replace tool: https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

Comment: More about the flags than the RegExp, e.g. `~^http://[^\v]+/wp-content/uploads[^\v]+$~mg` it needs to be multiline (m) and global (g): https://regex101.com/r/hId37t/1

Comment: You may want to go with [`http://[^\s'"]+?wp-content/uploads/[^\s"']+`](https://www.regex101.com/r/2MREiE/1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

something like that:

```
<?php
$strings = [
    'http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/image.jpg',
    'https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/image2.jpg',
    'http://example.com/wp-content/plugins/example-plugin/images/image.jpg'
];
$pattern = '/(http[^s]).+(wp-content\/uploads/)(.+)/';
foreach ($strings as $subject) {
    if (preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches)) {
        echo $matches[3] . "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of using `foreach` and `preg_match`, you should consider to use `preg_grep`.

Comment: That is not what OP wants `I do not want to capture the wp-content/uploads/`

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking for a YES/NO then the following would work:

```
http[^s].*wp-content\/uploads\/
```

See https://regex101.com/r/kPxOMt/1 for an example.

If you're looking to capture part of the url, please tell me and I'll update the regex.

Answer (score 0):

> I do not want to capture the wp-content/uploads/

```
$res = '';
if (preg_match('~(http://.*?)wp-content/uploads/(\S*)~', $string, $m) {
    $res = $m[1] . $m[2];
}
```

Comment: According to OP *These strings are present in `post_content` and other database columns on a WordPress installation* this won't guarantee matching [the right things](https://www.regex101.com/r/r9g9oG/1).

Comment: @revo:Thanks for edit ;) OP needs to show real strings before giving a completly valid regex. This one works on actualy given examples.